# Clamav (ubuntu 18.04): unable to update database and start scan

Tags: clamav

I want to scan my computer for malicious files. I know viruses on Ubuntu 18.04, and other linux distros, are rare to none existent, but I want to be sure.

I installed clamav with the normal sudo apt install clamav,  and afterwards tried to update the database with sudo freshclam. However, doing this left me with these errors:

[terminal error output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RZny3.png)

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Okay so I solved it. What is needed to be done is:

1) Manually download the database (daily.cvd) from their website and move it to /var/lib/clamav/.

2) After that try sudo freshclam again, if success then you are done.

3) OPTIONAL: If you get error missing file clamd.sock, then you need to create one with touch in /var/lib/clamav/ and give ownership of the file to clamav with chown. Also, in the config file /etc/clamav/clamd.conf uncomment and fix the path for LocalSocket.

Comment: Thanks so much, this is required for freshclam to work properly on Fedora 34!